# Incremental training of Topic Models in MALLET

Tags: topic-modeling, mallet

According to the MALLET [documentation](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php), it's possible to train topic models incrementally:

> "-output-model [FILENAME] This option specifies a file to write a
>   serialized MALLET topic trainer object. This type of output is
>   appropriate for pausing and restarting training"

I'd like to train topics on one set of data and then increment the model with a different set of data. After both training steps, I'd like to output states for both datasets (with --output-state). Here is how I try to do it:

```
# training on the first dataset
../mallet-2.0.7/bin/mallet import-dir --input input/ --keep-sequence --output input.mallet
../mallet-2.0.7/bin/mallet train-topics --input  input.mallet --num-topics 3 --output-state topic-state.gz --output-model model

# training on the second dataset
../mallet-2.0.7/bin/mallet import-dir --input input2/ --keep-sequence --output input2.mallet  --use-pipe-from input.mallet
../mallet-2.0.7/bin/mallet train-topics --input  input2.mallet --num-topics 3  --num-iterations 100 --output-state topic-state2.gz --input-model model
```

In the last command, if I add " --input-model model", the data from the 2nd dataset is not present in the output-state file. If I don't add it, the data from the 1st dataset is not present in the output-state file.

If I try to add additional instances to a model in the code:

```
model.addInstances(instances);
model.setNumThreads(2);
model.setNumIterations(50);
model.estimate();

[...]

model.addInstances(instances2);
model.setNumThreads(2);
model.setNumIterations(50);
model.estimate();
```

I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30
    at cc.mallet.topics.ParallelTopicModel.buildInitialTypeTopicCounts(ParallelTopicModel.java:364)
    at cc.mallet.topics.ParallelTopicModel.addInstances(ParallelTopicModel.java:276)
    at cc.mallet.examples.TopicModel2.main(TopicModel2.java:66)
```

There have been similar questions on the MALLET list before: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.mallet.devel/924, http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.mallet.devel/2139

So is incremental training of topic models possible?

Comment: have you figured out whether this is is possible @vpekar?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were part of this conversation thread which may be useful for you now.

```
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.mallet.devel/2153
```